# Is there an event that triggers when the app is closed?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

As the title says.

Specifically, I am writing an app that prints data to files over the course of runtime. I want to know when I can tell my `PrintWriter`s to save the files. I understand that I can probably do autosave every X minutes, but I am wondering if Android Studio will let me save on close instead. I tried using `onDestroy` but the code block never executed. (To be precise, I started the app, did a few things, closed the app, clicked Recents, and swiped the app away. The debugger showed that the app never got to that code.)

My current solution attempts to catch the surrounding circumstances by checking for key presses but this only works for the back and volume buttons and not the home, recent, or power buttons.

```java
    @Override public boolean onKeyDown(int key, KeyEvent event) {
        
        close();
        return false;
        
    }
```

Comment: implement onStop() instead will surely execute.

Comment: please check if onTerminate() in Application class helps

Comment: when you say "closed the app" does it mean there's button to click to exit the app, or the user simply press home button ?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the activity lifecycle:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

Or if you're using a fragment:
https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle

Consider using one of these two:

```java
    @Override public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        close();
    }
```

```java
    @Override public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        close();
    }
```

Comment: Its not onStop and onPause.  For saving, its onSaveInstanceState() (and onResumeInstanceState)

Comment: as my understanding, OP is asking how to trigger a function whenever he close the apps. as he said the workaround is by using timer and triggering every x minutes.

so it's not asking about how to save a state of the apps.

Answer (score 1):

There's a built in hook to the Activity lifecycle to save your state-  onSaveInstanceState.  There's even a bundle passed into you to save your state into for it to be restored (the matching function is onResumeInstanceState).  And as a free bonus, if you call super.onSaveInstanceState and super.onRestoreInstanceState, it will automatically save the UI state of your app for all views with an id.

Comment: OP is asking how to trigger a function whenever he close the apps, not about how to save and resume the state of the apps

Comment: @kinggg No, the OP is a newbie and doesn't know what he should be asking.  Hooking app termination is not a good idea on Android.  This is what he should be using instead.

Comment: @kinggf Also, waiting for termination to do anything on any OS is generally a bad idea when it comes to saving data.  Why?  Because abnormal termination exists.  If you crash, or the OS needs to just immediately kill the process, all that data is lost as the terminate functions won't (and sometimes can't) be called.  So periodic (either time based or milestone based) saving should be used alongside that if you want to minimize data loss.

Comment: I agreed with you, but I'm just providing answer from what OP asked

he was asking how to trigger a function, and his case was trigging a function "PrintWriter" which is save to file.